# Read more button for tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Good Morning!
I would like to ask your help for solving this problem:
I want to add a read more button to my tumblr blog, but the one what the site provides isn't right for my goals. I need the button to toggle the 'closed' class on the appropriate 'body-text' class element.

I have this code:

```
 ._readmore {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .closed {
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }



  $(document).ready(function(){
       $("._readmore").click(function(){
         $(".body-text").toggleClass("closed");
       });
    });
```

The problem is, if i click one of the '_readmore' class elements all of the 'body-text' class elements will loose the closed class.

(the blog: http://fiktivcikkek.tumblr.com/)

Thanks for your help.
Levente

Comment: use `CSS` `JS` is not **required** `.body-text.closed + ._readmore { ... }` ``.body-text + ._readmore { ... }`` more about [+ selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Comment: But I want to display only a fragment of the text until the user don't click on the '_readmore ' class  text. And then reveal the full content of that post. If I unterstand correctly your answer (which I am not sure about), this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: My problem is that, my code reveals all articles full content after the '_readmore' class element have been clicked. But I want to reveal only that articles full content which the read more button belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".body-text").toggleClass("closed"); // will select all the classes
```

you need to change your code to this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("._readmore").click(function() {
    $(this).prev('.body-text').toggleClass("closed"); // to select the previous element of ._readmore class
  });
});
```

Comment: I am not at home at the moment but I will try this as soon as I get home. Will this work if the read more div and the body-text div are in the same container (div) or it only works only if the body-text is in the read more div?

Comment: Oh... I would have another tiny question: How should modify the code if i want it to work when there is another div between the read more and the body-text div?